# RoR newbie: Regarding rails setup and rubygems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm beginning to learn Ruby on Rails, I installed the latest ubuntu release on a VMWare machine and started the ruby on rails setup process using the mini-guide in [this online book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#main_content) (which was recommended in stack overflow more than once). I'm wondering:

As part of my environment setup process I installed RubyGems and used it to install Rails (which is, if I understand correctly - a gem itself) the first time.

Now, when creating a new project using `rails new project_name` I later on edit the Gemfile and specify "rails '{version}'", which, from what I understand, installs the Rails gem in the context of the project (after using `bundle install`)...

Why would I need both of them? I'm kind of confused and would be more than happy if someone could shed some light over this...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bit confusing.

When you run `rails new project_name`, you are using whatever `rails` executable is available in your shell to start a new rails project. To see what version this is, run `rails —version`. This does not "install the rails gem" — it just generates the tree of files to get you started on a new rails project.

You'll then specify in your Gemfile which version of rails your project will use.

So, be sure to have the latest version of rails available to your shell when you generate your new project, so that you get the newest version of the files it generates.

Comment: So basically, gem install rails -v {version} takes care of all the "tools" I need to create a rails project (including the executable you mentioned above plus the various rails related gems).
Now, when creating a new rails project (using rails new {project_name}), I need to specify inside the Gemfile the rails version which is installed on my computer plus any other gem files I want to include in my project, and since I may have various versions installed on my computer, I have the option to specify each gem version?

Comment: "including the executable you mentioned above — nope — the executable used to generate the project is, of course, already on your computer, because you just used it :-) the rails gem just so happens to come with an executable that generates new rails projects. They could have named it rails_tool or something, and could have distributed it separately from the framework gem, but chose not to for convenience. Maybe a good next step is to go watch some screencasts about Bundler.